# Problem in using zip2john tool to take hash values

Tags: hashing, linux

I have take a zip file from NFS port using `sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.105/backup /tmp/kevgir` .

After that, I got `backup.tar.bz2.zip` file in `/tmp/kevgir` directory. I crack the zip file using `fcrackzip` tool, but I also wanted to crack it using John the ripper.

For this aim, I wanted to take the hash value of zip file using `zip2john` tool. However, when I write

```
zip2john /tmp/kevgir/backup.tar.bz2.zip > /tmp/kevgir/hash.txt
```

It gives me

```
zsh: read-only file system: /tmp/kevgir/hash.txt
```

Properties of zip file is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13058028 Feb 14  2016 backup.tar.bz2.zip
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: What partition is your /tmp/ partition mounted on?

Comment: `/tmp/kevgir/hash.txt` cannot be created, try to write it somewhere else.

Comment: @ThoriumBR i tried it in desktop, but still same

Comment: why are you giving us the properties of the zip file when the error is about the txt file or the directory where you want to write?